# How to find current executing event in javascript, jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two very similar function that are called on different events i.e. 1st on 'onmousedown' and 2nd on 'onmouseup' . I am thinking to merge them into one to improve maintainability of my code. My problem is how could I find the current event inside switch statement ?

```
function update_button_to_idle(id){
var img = 'images/';

switch(id){
    case 'abc1':        
        img += 'enter1.png';
        break;  
    case 'abc2':    
    case 'abc3':
                img += 'play1.png';
        break;
   }
    $('#' + id + ' img').attr('src', img);
}

function update_button_to_active(id){
var img = 'images/';

switch(id){
    case 'abc1':        
        img += 'enter2.png';
        break;  
    case 'abc2':    
    case 'abc3':
                img += 'play2.png';
        break;
   }
    $('#' + id + ' img').attr('src', img);
}
```

Comment: how is the event registered? and how is these methods called

Comment: If you can get hold of the `event` object then you can use `event.type` to identify the event

Comment: pass it in from event.type as a second parameter to the function

Comment: I am calling my methods like this:- <div id="test1" onmousedown="update_button_to_active(this.id);" onmouseup="update_button_to_idle(this.id);">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `onXXX` attributes, bind your handlers using jQuery:

```
$("selector").on("mousedown mouseup", function(event) {
    update_button(this.id, event.type);
}
```

Then combine your functions into one `update_button()` function that takes two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the event is registered - if you pass in the event to the function you can identify it by calling the event.type. For example:

```
function (event) {
   if (event.type == "mousedown") {

   }

}
```

Without knowing more about how the event is triggered, its hard to give you a complete answer.